# Smart CVS and Core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cvs

I have a smart cvs installed on my iMac, and i have update the application from the cvs.
Then i did some changes on my code and on the core data ( core data changes are: remove some attributes from core data entity), then i tried to commit the changes to cvs, BUT i get the following error:

Up-to-date check failed for `xxxxxxx.m' , (i.e xxxxxxx is the file name).
command aborted.

What do you think about this error? how to solve it, and get the successful commit ?

Thx a lot

Comment: Are you saying you updated the Core Data model itself (when you are removing attributes)?

Comment: I removed some attributes from core data model, then i try to commit these changes to cvs server, and got that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try update then commit, if this is not solve problem mark core data as removed files

Answer (score 2):

That's the common error message of the CVS server if you try to commit a change which is newer available on the server. Perform an update first.

Comment: If I update first, then the core data will updated from cvs and the attributes that i remove them will return back to core data module

Answer (score 0):

Try running a clean by either hitting command-shift-k or going to Product->Clean. Then try to build again.  If that fails, try copying the contents of the file somewhere else, move it to trash (when you select delete it will say remove references or move to trash, you want move to trash), then create the file again and copy in the code. Just some things to try.

Comment: What file you are talking about? the error occurs because cvs can't commit the core data model